# Coordinates in OpenLayers and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, coordinates, openlayers

First, I'm Spanish so, sorry for my English.

I have a problem with the coordinates and the OpenLayers.

The problem is that the function called "mapa_tren" is working when I write the coordinates directly in the code, if I write this:

```
geometry: new ol.geom.Point(transformacion(-4.231575155, 43.308034436))
```

The map is showing properly, but if I write this:

```
geometry: new ol.geom.Point(transformacion(resp.long, resp.lat )),
```

The map is showing in the ocean.

I checked the json, I Checked the functions which is using the json and I dind't find anything wrong

Here is the code:

```
    function transformacion(lng, lat) {//Funcion para convertir las coordenadas
       return ol.proj.transform([lng, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    }
```

function mapa_tren(resp) {// Funcion que contiene el código para mostrar el mapa

```
var capa1 = new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
      });

 var capa2 = new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'hyb'})
      });


var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({ 
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point(transformacion(resp.long, resp.lat )),
   //geometry: new ol.geom.Point(transformacion(-4.231575155, 43.308034436)),
   name: 'Tren'
});


var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    opacity: 0.75,
    src: 'icono_localizacion.png'
    }))
});

iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [iconFeature]
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
});


 var map = new ol.Map({
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    layers: [capa1, capa2, vectorLayer],
    view: new ol.View({
      //center: ol.proj.transform([longitud, latitud ], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      center: ol.proj.transform([-4.231575155, 43.308034436 ], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      //center: [0,0],
      zoom: 7
    })
  });

}

function call_map(resp){
    mapa_tren(resp)
}


$.post('serv.php',{vble: 'real_sorpheo'}, function (json){ call_map(json) },"json")
```

Comment: The EPSG:3857 coordinate should be -471056.791508068, 5358975.97976077. I just did this in Postgis. What value are you getting back from transformacion? Y tu nivel de inglés es bastante bien, no te preocupes :D.

Comment: Yes, when I put directly -4.231575155, 43.308034436. The value I'm getting back is almost the same -471056.79150806775, 5358975.979760781. When I use JSON, I get the information from a URL, and I have this coordinates -7.056000613, 43.536769981. And this is the value i'm getting back from transformacion -785470.3952761862, -5854895.462540525

Comment: Can you post the JSON, enough to reproduce the problem, anyway?

Comment: Sure. Here it is the JSON: {"long":"-7.056106436","lat":"43.536748979","fecha":"2014-10-24 12:50:01","velocidad":"0","real_time":false,"uptime_seconds":"300000","refresh_ms":"30000"}. I get "long", and "lat" from here

Comment: I have the same problem, using OL3 and a valid json. Entering numeric coordinates works, but not the JSON obtained variables. Putting everything out in the console shows correct values, yet the error remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

As expressed under comments, I had the same problem: using numeric coordinates works, while placing the json content variable results in failure.

The solution is simple, all we need is a parseFloat done on json returns:

```js
// add to map   
var mapItem = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([parseFloat(unit.longitude), parseFloat(unit.latitude)])),
        name: unit.devid,
        online: unit.online,
        outdoor: unit.outdoor,
        chart24h: "http://www.uradmonitor.com/data/0.1/charts/'+unit.devid+'.usvh.png"  
});
vectorSource.addFeature(mapItem);
```

This did the trick for me:
[image]